# deferRender not working on 5,000+ row ajax sourced table/Scroller plugin (dataTables)

Tags: datatables

My datatables table has an ajax/json data source and I am trying to implement scroller/deferred rendering and it doesn't seem to be doing anything. The load speed is exactly the same as before I added scroller.

Heres my datatables init:

```
var dTable = $('#resultTable').dataTable({
    "oLanguage": { "sSearch": "Filter All Rows By:",
                    "sInfo": "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ Hospitals",
                    "sProcessing":     "Please be patient while hospital data is retrieved...  <img style='margin-bottom:5px;' height='30px' width='30px' src='load/wheel.png'/>"
    },
     "columnDefs": [ {
            "searchable": false,
            "orderable": false,
            "targets": 0
     }
    ],
    "processing": true,
    "bDeferRender": true,
    "Dom": '<"clear">lfrtipTS',
    "order": [],
    "scrollY":        "600px",
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bPaginate": false,
    "sScrollX": "100%",
    "sScrollXInner": "100%",
    "ajax": {
            "url": "query/query_providerlist.php?recordnum=<?php echo $recordnum ?>&prvdrnum=<?php echo $num ?>&prvdrname=<?php echo $name ?>&cbsa=<?php echo $cbsa ?>&urbanrural=<?php echo $urbanrural ?>&ownertype=<?php echo $ownertype ?>&prvdrstrt=<?php echo $prvdrstrt ?>&prvdrcity=<?php echo $prvdrcity ?>&prvdrstate=<?php echo $state ?>&county=<?php echo $county ?>&prvdrzip=<?php echo $prvdrzip ?>",
            "dataType": "json"
        },
        "aoColumns": [
            {"data": null, "bSortable":false},
            {"data": "provider_num"},
            {"data": "provider_name",
             "mRender": function ( data, type, row ) {
             return '<a href="#provmodal" data-toggle="modal" class="push" id='+row.id+'>'+row.provider_name+'</a>'; 
             }
            },
            {"data": "state"},
            {"data": "city"},
            {"data": "street"},
            {"data": "county"},
            {"data": "zip", "sClass": "rightAlign"},
            {"data": "cbsa", "sClass": "rightAlign"}
        ],
    fnDrawCallback : function( oSettings ) {
       $(this).find('tbody tr').each(function(index) {
         $(this).find('td').first(0).text(index+1);
       });
     }
    });
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong to initialize deferRender/Scroller but I know it's not working because at the bottom of my table it says `Displaying 1 to 5,684 of 5,684 entries` and I know that scroller is supposed to make it say something like `displaying 1 to x(based on table height) of 5,684 entries`.

Any advice would be awesome.

thanks in advance

Comment: Did you ever find a fix/workaround for this? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: Me too! What's the solution for this? :(
deferRender seems to be making no difference for my ajax sourced data. If I simply enable serverSide, then my loading time is significantly reduced, but why does deferRender not work!?

Comment: I found out that deferRender only stops your data from populating the HTML dom so extra TD and TR elements are not created until you view the next pages. My main delay in loading the datatable was because my ajax sourced data was taking too much time to download. deferRender will not affect the time it takes to load your ajax data, so the only way to reduce loading time is to reduce your ajax data. For example if page length is 10 and you're on the first page, ajax should return only 10 records. I used server side processing to implement this solution. Hope that helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Late answer here, but hopefully useful. You must make sure that your sever side code is only returning the requested number of results based on the position of the scroller. Datatables with `serverSide: true` passes default [params](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) that include `start` and `length`. Use these values to skip and limit records so you only return the records that should be returned for that page, and not the entire result set.